# black screen between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an application, in which after playing an animation, an interactive activity starts. The last frame of the animation and activity background is same so that the transition from the animation to the interactive activity can be hidden. But when i switch from one activity to another, there comes a black screen(for a fraction of second). I tried  overridePendingTransition(0,0) also. But its not working.

How can i avoid this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check info at [Black Screen while Switching between applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669855/black-screen-while-switching-between-applications)

Comment: how do you call the second activity?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371896/3050249