# Black Screen while Switching between applications

Tags: android, performance

I have two apps and when i switch from one app to another a black screen is displayed for a while and then the 2nd application starts, can we stop this from happening?

Comment: I consider this the best piece of writing on how to make Android apps (seem to) start faster: ['Android App Launching Made Gorgeous' by Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/). It explains the details behind the answer below by @MobileAppsExpert

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way is to move all the expensive (time-consuming) processing from your activity's **onCreate** and **onStart** method to **onResume** method. By this, your newly launched activity will be visible right after its launched but then will take a little extra to make it available for user to interact. Further, I would suggest you to move all the heavy lifting in **AsyncTask** for smoother UI experience.

You can also try this theme for your Activity

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme" />

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_app_background</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: But still the UI component will take some time and the black screen would be displayed.

Comment: Please try once these theme and there is some more Themes available in android to avoid that black screen. 
like
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
       
    </style>

Comment: Got your point....bt this will only only change the theme and delay in start would be there.

Comment: Yes,it will take time to load, You will not get any black screen.
You can optimize your code to reduce delay in loading screen.
Once try these approach , you will definitely got some good result

Comment: Will have to wait for more answers to see anyone knows more about this. anyway Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Ankit "this will only change the theme and delay in start would be there" - The theme is what gets displayed while the app starts. Your current theme is a black screen. Change the theme with a suitable background, and the app will look like it is appearing while it starts up. Full details in a comment below original answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you switching between fragments through screen manager kind of class, which uses enums and fragment transaction to switch between fragments; make sure you put a break statement, after each enum case. This solved my issue. Hope it helps!