# Blackscreen behind activity when animating

Tags: android

I'm using:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
```

The problem is that I want the *push_left_out animation* to have the *overshoot interpolator*. Here is the code for the animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="650"/> 
</set>
```

When this animation appears, a black screen is behind the activity and I don't want to use a translucent theme to solve this issue. I want the black screen to become white.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468349/how-to-remove-black-background-between-start-new-activity-during-slide-left-anim

Comment: In that post he didnt have ana naimation in the exit animation but i have one

Comment: @sasikumar and i also said i dont want to use a translucent theme

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the android:background in the very root of your project layout to white color