# overridePendingTransition in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

My main activity uses tablayout with a viewpager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I want to open a new activity with a custom animation from one of my fragments and close it again with animation. When I open it, the only thing I see is a black screen. This is how I do it:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Fragment{
    ...
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, ACTIVITY_RESULT);
    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,
                           R.anim.animation_leave);
    ...
}


public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", updatesPerformed);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_leave,
                           R.anim.animation_enter);
    ...
}
```

I tried to move the method in different places but the animation still doesn't work and I see only black screen. If I pause and resume to the same activity I see it.

Comment: If you comment out `overridePendingTransition`, same black screen is happened?

Comment: no without it everything is as normal

Comment: It is odd.. can you post animation_leave.xml and animation_enter.xml ?

Comment: I changed them a few times with the exact same ones as the tutorials - the problem is not there, for what I know. And yes, it is very odd. The device I use is nexus 6 by the way.

Comment: I think I can't reproduce this issue without your xml file. Will this issue be happened with  pre-set animations like `android.R.anim.slide_in_left` and `android.R.anim.slide_out_right` ?

Comment: lol. I changed it to android.R.anim.fade_in and android.R.anim.fade_out and it works. I will add the xml files in the question.

Comment: The other xml files work as well, I am not sure how today the problem is fixed by itself. Must be android studio. Anyway, thanks for the help @nshmura

Comment: You can refer this link <i>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468349/how-to-remove-black-background-between-start-new-activity-during-slide-left-anim</i>

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I really hope someone can help me with it... Whenever I attempt to put `                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
` after `startActivity(intent);`, `overridePendingTransaction` turns red and returns "cannot resolve method" error. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

very simple use this code in your fragment

```
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out CodingInFlow's solution: 
[Slide Animation Between Activities](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/slide-animation-between-activities)

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openActivity2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, 
        R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
}
```

**activity_2.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is Activity 2"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity2.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
            R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer but you need to define from the second activity that how it will translate in and out.
e.g

**In First Fragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), My_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**In Second Activity**

```
@override
public void finish(){
  super.finish();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

**OR**

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this can solve your problem