# Activity transition black screen

Tags: android, android-animation

So I've got WelcomeActivity -> HomeActivity and closing WelcomeActivity with `finish()/supportFinishAfterTransition()`. I want to do either a slideTransition or a fadeTransition (open to other suggestions btw).

I've researched this and as it turns out there are 2+ ways of doing it: either with  `overridePendingTransition` which uses anim.xml files or with Transitions (from the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity)) which use transition.xml files...

I've tried both and both give me unwanted results:

1. for anims: I get this ugly mid transition black screen:

fade_in.xml:

```
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0"
       android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="300" />
```

fade_out.xml:

```
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:zAdjustment="top"
       android:duration="300" />
```

WelcomeActivity: (I've tried having finish before the overridePendingTransaction)

```
    startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
    finish()
```

2. for transitions: I can't make it so WelcomeActivity closes properly: It either closes before the animation starts or not closing at all. I'm following the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity).. I've also tried this:

style.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/enter_fade</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/exit_fade</item>
```

My other questions is which approach should I have? Is Google pushing the transitions over the anims for starting new activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always do is to start an activity(any way you want, ways are [listed here](https://genicsblog.com/ways-to-open-a-new-activity-in-an-android-app)).
I use slide transitions using these two files:

### slide_out_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

### slide_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Then I start an activity like this(this is [java](/questions/tagged/java)):

```
startActivity(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right.xml, R.anim.slide_in_left.xml);
finish();
```

Using this, the activity exits giving way to the new one smoothly from right to left.
For the black screen, set the theme of that activity as translucent in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

so your code will be something like this

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Answer for the black screen taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468734/9819031

Comment: I think you've got a mistake: both slide_in and slide_out are going from -100 to 0

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit. While copying I did it by mistake, I'll edit just now

Comment: And yes, this is fin but I don't think it's appropriate for my situation as I'm going from a screen WITHOUT a Navigation bar to a screen with one so it just looks a bit weird. As for the fade I still can't make it work without the black screen.