# Start Activity with animation black screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

Hello I'm adding animation left to right and right to left when opening and finishing activities but when I put the `overridePendingIntent` it shows a black screen...

This is my left_to_right.xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

This is the right_to_left.xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

I'm starting the Activity like this :

```
startActivity(Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java))
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left)
```

and finishing it like this :

```
finish()
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.left_to_right)
```

But when doing it is showing black screen...

This is my theme

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And on my Activities I'm using

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690764/overridependingtransition-for-sliding-activities-in-and-out-smoothly)

Comment: or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971082/activity-transition-black-screen#What%20I%20always%20do%20is%20to%20start%20an)

Comment: How do I adapt my theme to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
?

Comment: Did my answer helped you? please let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST ACTIVITY:**

I rebuild the situation with a `MainActivity` that inflates the `TargetActivity` (second `Activity`) using a `Button`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button_in = findViewById(R.id.button_in);
        button_in.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        });
    }
}
```

The `activity_main.xml` contains the first `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2962FF"
        android:text="To TargetActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**SECOND ACTIVITY:**

The second `Activity` is the `TargetActivity` that `finish()` with an animation like this:

```
public class TargetActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_target);

        Button button_out = findViewById(R.id.button_out);
        button_out.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        });
    }
}
```

And also another `Layout` with the 2nd `Button` called `activity_target.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFAB00"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".TargetActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#2962FF"
        android:text="To MainActivity" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**4 ANIMATIONS:**

All you need is 4 animations in your `anim` folder. 2 for left to right and also vice versa.

1.) `slide_in_left.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

2.) `slide_out_left.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

3.) `slide_in_right.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

4.) `slide_out:right.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

---

Finally don't forget to add the `TargetActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".TargetActivity"/>
```

[image: Left to right and vice versa]

Comment: Adding the windowIsTranslucent true doesn't work... and the problem is not the exit, even if I do not put anything on the second Activity it doesn't work the entry animation

Comment: Oke. let me rebuild your project soon. I will make an example with exit and entry animation :D

Comment: Thanks, let me now if you can make it work.

Comment: I rebuild it. Hope that helps. Feel free to tick the answer as correct and happy Coding! Cheers :)