# Android: Removing Space/Black Bar Between Activity Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

I have two activities: ***Activity1*** and ***Activity2***. I wish to have *Activity2* slide in from the bottom of *Activity1* while at the same time *Activity1* pushes out.

However, there is a black gap between the activities (see figure below).

[image: gap between the activities]

The following is my code for transitions.

**slide_in_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="100.0%p" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_top.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="100.0%p" />
</set>
```

So my question is: *how do I get rid of this gap/black space?* I've checked out sources here on StackOverflow and I a Translucent theme doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
```

Or, if you have a particular background,

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.bg ));
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396465/1510502

Comment: Nice! Work fine